# How to resolve Argument of type 'X' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' when manipulating an array in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have [this long list of types](https://github.com/teamtreesurf/base.link/blob/99f217f0f06d2553300b91eb53c4377b201c1da0/make/type/mesh/code.ts), which essentially boil down to the following:

- All types have a `like` property set to an enum constant.
- The `Partial` types have a `children` array property.
- Each `Partial` accepts different types of items in the `children` array.
- The `Full` types don't have a `children` property, they have other properties.

Given that, I am writing this simple function to replace a child item with another item, which should match the possible types in `children` for that object. Essentially just `children.splice(children.indexOf(item), 1)`, but in TypeScript form:

```
export function replaceASTChild<
  A extends AST,
  X extends ASTPartialType<AST>,
  B extends ASTType<AST>,
>(input: APIInputType, a: A, x: X, b: B): void {
  // irrelevant, gets the input.scope.parent (1 parent up)
  const objectScope = api.assumeObjectScope(input, 1)
  // assert the object
  api.assertASTPartial(objectScope.data, a)
  const index = objectScope.data.children.indexOf(x)
  objectScope.data.children[index] = b
}
```

How do I replace it properly and avoid the error in the title?

Here is a [minimal example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAggSQHYEsQoIYBsAqlYC8MA3sDDAMYAWKWAJgE5RIBc8DDGYAPAM4gMUSAOYA+YAF9gofPABiQ7HmgwipcgDMA9lrb9BIydPAqAQsjSZcstWUo16TVu048kAVwC2AIygNxUjJmCkhKNiR23hgMbB4+fkZBsADCFuhhKrbk1LSMzGxwHFzciKjp1ioAPjDmZVbKsNVwIRmNNS0VUAHGsskdDaoR5GhQnrwFRTzNip0w1ab9+N1JMAAaafXhpZatczUbrSuri5nyMwPzJ1DSUAAeEFoMIDAa7kgU6FpIMEwQWBgUKDJBx0AAUFC+IAwQj8bHWdVaABoYCNPHoBEJhHs4r4GMjfv9AZ5mCA4VcAJRsABuWhQdCGlC+-BRSDod0GEKQUJhDAAdDlHMxeUI2bcAPIaUGo8l2TncpB+fkgpwAbRFdwAuoMCQDRiTEpzmVAsHquQcsABGArmgZZey5JxsFUAcioxqwWhgAHdHvRnRqjIbnnLoQqGFaYKkEbM7QK8s4VcbTSBzRaA4EdYDgblwZDQ34Lcik8SzdHCyQXjo2K73Z6fQw-TAJOSgA) to demonstrate the errors I am facing.

```
type AInitialType = {
  children: Array<string>
}

type AFinalType = {
  foo: string
}

type BInitialType = {
  children: Array<number>
}

type BFinalType = {
  bar: number
}

type CInitialType = {
  children: Array<AInitialType | BInitialType | AFinalType | BFinalType>
}

type CFinalType = {
  items: Array<AFinalType | BFinalType>
}

type XInitialType = AInitialType | BInitialType
type XFinalType = AFinalType | BFinalType

export function replaceChild(container: XInitialType, item: string | number, replacement: XFinalType): void {
  const index = container.children.indexOf(item)
  container.children[index] = replacement
}

const elementInitial1: AInitialType = {
  children: ['hello world']
}
const container1: CInitialType = {
  children: [elementInitial1]
}

replaceChild(container1, elementInitial1, { foo: 'hello world' })
```

Comment: This will be hard (or even impossible) to properly troubleshoot without a reproducable example.

Comment: Updated with a minimal example at the end.